# Añadir archivo .js externo a un componente html de Angular (Error tipo MIME)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Estoy intentando añadir un .js a mi proyecto de Angular pero obtengo el error:

> El recurso de “http://.../archivo.js" fue bloqueado debido a una discordancia del tipo MIME (“text/html”) (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

El achivo esta en assets :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y debidamente referenciado en su archivo angular.json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con su correspondiente etiqueta script en el index.html

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="src/assets/JS/login.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Leyendo el foro oficial de Angular he visto que existe el mismo problema , pero las soluciones que aqui se plantean no me funcionan.

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325

¿Ideas?

Comment: no tienes que agregar la etiqueta `script` eso se hace al agregarlo en el angular.json

Comment: ¿y como lo pondrias ?¿ o nisiquiera lo tendrias que poner el index.html?

Comment: no se coloca en el index.html, simplemente se agrega al angular.json